# Python / Jupyter Notebook Slide buttons gone?

Tags: python, jupyter, rise

I am using Jupyter Notebook to build slides. Until yesterday there were two buttons right from the CellToolBar button to start the slide show (one button was RISE.js). All of the sudden these buttons are gone. Now there are **no buttons on the right side of the CellToolBar button at all.**

I tried `conda update jupyter` and `conda update -c damianavila82 rise` using the terminal. 
But I get the message `# All requested packages already installed`. So the issue appears to be somewhere else.

Does anyone know what I could do to restore the buttons?

- I am on a mac
- The version of the jupyter notebook server is 4.3.1
- RISE version is 4.0.0b1
- Anaconda is 4.3.0
- Python 3.5.2

Thanks!

Comment: Is the extension installed/enabled? try the command  `jupyter nbextension list`, if it doesn't show up then it isn't installed, if it shows up but says `disabled` then it isn't enabled, if it shows up and says `enabled` then something else is wrong

Comment: Thanks. The rise/main extension appears to be disabled. Just installed nbextension tool and saw that many extension are disabled due to missing compatibility. For many it says that the yaml file is missing. I did not change anything manually. Do you know what happened and how I could fix this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "installed nbextension tool"? What tool is this? If it is disabled can you run `jupyter nbetension enable rise --py --sys-prefix`? This should enable the extension (you can check afterwards using `jupyter nbextension list` again). I've never heard anything about missing yaml files so you'd probably have to update your post with more detailed error messages and what commands they're coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check your nbextensions

```
http://localhost:8888/nbextensions?nbextension=rise/main
```

Some nbextensions like RISE get disabled automatically (e.g. if there could be issues with compatibilities, e.g. after updates).

[image]

Comment: I can't access to this page for some reason, how can I enable the slideshow button with anaconda?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on chrome, somehow the issue for me was solved by simply changing the jupyterlab theme to jupyterlab dark. This issue persisted only on the light theme. Although this might be a temporary fix for the issue.