# Jupyter Notebook's RISE Missing Slideshow Button

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda, reveal.js

I followed the [instructions](https://github.com/damianavila/RISE#installation) on installing [RISE](https://github.com/damianavila/RISE) for Jupyter notebook with Anaconda (conda) but the *"Enter/Exit RISE Slideshow"* button never showed in the toolbar.

I followed the recommendations on solving the problem in the two closed RISE issues ([#137](https://github.com/damianavila/RISE/issues/137), [#275](https://github.com/damianavila/RISE/issues/275)), but with no luck.  I updated Jupyter to the latest version, started a new notebook, hard refreshed the browser page, reinstalled Rise and still no button.

I also saw this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426498/python-jupyter-notebook-slide-buttons-gone), which is different from my case since I never saw the button, and I do not have nbextensions to begin with.  Still, their recommendation did not work.

For practical reasons, I cannot have a separate environment just for RISE and presentation making.

I'm having the same problem on two machines, with different operating systems and different Conda packages, so it may be a RISE package problem. On one of the machines, I have:

- Google Chrome 66.0.3359.117 (64-bit)
- conda 4.5.1 with python 3.6.4
- jupyter 1.0.0
- jupyter_core 4.3.0
- notebook 5.0.0
- rise 5.2.0 py36_0 damianavila82
- MacOS High Sierra (10.13.4)

My conda packages seem to be in good shape and without missing dependencies too.

```bsh
$ jupyter nbextension list
Known nbextensions:
  config dir: /Users/welshamy/Applications/anaconda3/etc/jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
      rise/main  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a package compatibility issue.  I solved the problem by doing the following:

1. Upgrade `conda` packages from the command line:

   ```sh
   $ conda update --all
   ```
2. Restart jupyter-notebook session.
3. Restart web browser.
4. Open a new notebook.
5. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the browser
if not create a new notebook

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue!

Here is what I did to resolve the issue:

1. First I install the pip library of rise

```bash
    pip install RISE
```

2. Then, I run the conda command

```bash
    conda install -c conda-forge rise
```

3. Now, Activate your conda

```bash
    conda activate
```

4. Now, run the below command.

```bash
    jupyter nbextension install rise --py --user
```

5. last, enable nbextension to use rise

```bash
    jupyter nbextension enable rise --py --user
```

For more detail, you can also refer to the following GitHub issue page: https://github.com/damianavila/RISE/issues/520

Answer (score 0):

```bash
pip install RISE
pip install jupyterlab_rise
```

I don't think the new version of rise has a button option in jupyter notebook anymore.

I installed rise and refreshed the web page, and the web page didn't show button. but I noticed that the browser disables popup behavior.
Allowed popups, refreshed the page, and automatically popped to a page showing the jupyter notebook slideshow.

Switch jupyternotebook to jupyterlab, there is a button for slideshow in the top right corner, click on it to show it as a slideshow.

Comment: Your post is leaving it a lot of details and as a result it may confuse more than it helps. In particular you are not using versions in reference to Jupyter interfaces. The latest says at the top [here for 'latest'(5.7.2.dev2)](https://rise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#): "Please be aware that the extension built from this repo is not compatible with JupyterLab and must be used with the classic notebook. JupyterLab and Notebook 7 users are encouraged to use the RISE JupyterLab extension instead". However, you don't say if you are using Jupyter Notebook 7+ or NbClassic or give any version ...

Comment: <continued> information at all. If you are not aware, Jupyter Notebook 7+ is built on JupyterLab tech and so is quite different than Jupyter Notebook version 6.5 and below and different than NbClassic. Please see references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004) if you need more help understanding. As a result of all that, I question if your statement "I don't think the new version of rise has a button option in jupyter notebook anymore" is valid. I cannot judge what you reference or if you adequately tested based on your limited information.

Comment: This is my supplementary details, including python version, jupyter version and the extension version.
via: https://i.imgur.com/0EWtqPX.png

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. The steps work for me.
Jupyter Notebook Version: 6.5.4
Python Version: 3.11.5 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Sep 11 2023, 13:26:23) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

Here is what I did to resolve the issue:

First I install the pip library of rise

```
pip install RISE
```

Then, I run the conda command

```
conda install -c conda-forge rise
```

Now, Activate your conda

```
conda activate
```

Now, run the below command.

```
 jupyter nbextension install rise --py --user
```

last, enable nbextension to use rise

```
 jupyter nbextension enable rise --py --user
```